# Gnome login bounces back to login screen. startx works

Tags: centos, rhel, gnome

After a reboot (maybe an update) on Centos Stream, I can't login anymore.

- default is `graphical.target`
- if I run the console mode, login and run `startx`, it works
- The login setting is set to `Standard X11 display server`
- The Centos' default display manager: I guess it's GDM (GNOME Display Manager)

What prevents the login screen from login?

I checked all the other questions, none solved it.

```
$ systemctl status display-manager
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-28 08:34:19 JST; 14min ago
 Main PID: 1884 (gdm)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 409474)
   Memory: 5.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
           └─1884 /usr/sbin/gdm

Feb 28 08:34:19 i9wspro systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Feb 28 08:34:19 i9wspro systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Feb 28 08:34:24 i9wspro gdm[1884]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Feb 28 08:34:27 i9wspro gdm[1884]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Feb 28 08:34:35 i9wspro gdm[1884]: Gdm: GdmCommon: process (pid:2049, command 'gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]') isn't dying after 5 seconds, now ignoring it.
Feb 28 08:50:30 i9wspro gdm[1884]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
```

After each login attempt, it adds `gdm[1884]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing`

- `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

```
# GDM configuration storage

[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

#AutomaticLoginEnable=True
#AutomaticLogin=alexis

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
#Enable=true
```

- `systemctl list-units --failed`:

[image]

Comment: Which display manager?

Comment: `gdm`, I added the systemctl status log and the gdm conf file.

Comment: Have you got a Nvidia GPU?

Comment: I used a `GTX1050-TI` for a 2nd display but I unplugged everything and I'm currently running only on the intel's iGPU to try debugging that. Let me know what file can be useful.

Comment: Could you test a different DM?

Comment: `lightdm` has conflicts with `x11-xorg`, `sddm` installed and enabled, rebooting

Comment: I see the mouse arrow with black screen and ctrl+alt+f1 shows it stuck at boot (plymouth). Rebooting to multi-user and startx, still works.

Comment: Could you revert to gdm and run `systemctl list-units --failed` in tty2? Please add the output to your question

Comment: Nothing failed. Nevertheless, when I press enter to login (graphic) I see displaying 3 lines with the last one red but it reverts to the login screen too fast to read them.

Comment: I see you have a fairly customized terminal prompt.  Have made any changes to your shell’s dotfiles lately?  It sounds to me like it is unable to launch your session.

Comment: Really? It's a simple PS1 with colors, nothing fancy at all. I use it in tens of servers. Logging `tty2` and entering `startx` loads my session correctly as it does from the login screen previously. Something's wrong with the login screen. I tried to remove and re-install "GNOME" without any success. I'd like to avoid reinstalling everything, if somehow I know which files/folders to delete to reset gnome... Which log file should I look at? Definitely there is something printing at that moment.

Comment: `I see displaying 3 lines with the last one red but it reverts to the login screen too fast to read them` ... record a video with a smartphone  ... you may get lucky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new user and I could login without any problem.

I removed all the dotfiles and dotfolders of my user, I could login but I lost all the extensions and so on.